# Add data in openoffice calc document using php

Tags: php

I have openoffice calc document which contains a few empty tables.
Is there an any way to add data from php to the openoffice calc document in table cells ?

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way would be for your php write a comma-separated (.csv) file and then read that into Calc.
e.g.

```
// write example .csv file
$handle= fopen("myfile.csv","w");
for($row=0; $row<10; $row++){
  for($col=0; $col<10; $col++)
    fputs( $handle, $row+$col . (($col<9)?",":"\n") );
  fputs($handle,"\n");
}
fclose($handle);
```

Yours,
Tonywilk

Comment: Can you explain me how to read data from .csv file into Calc?

Comment: Calc will read .csv files - just open it or Insert/Sheet from file.

Comment: But I have ready table in Calc document, I need to insert values in  table cells.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess there's 3 ways you could look at this: (1) interface directly with Calc - don't have a clue-sorry. (2) manipulate a saved calc.ods file - it's a zip containing .xml documents so it should be possible with difficulty. (3) use calc to write a .csv file and read/modify that in php.